# How many digits does $2^{1000}$ contain?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, logarithms, decimal-expansion

I tried this way, I only need to know if this is correct or if there are better ways to solve this:

$2^{1000}$ does not have a factor of $5$ obviously therefore we can assume

$$ 10^{m} < 2^{1000} < 10^{m+1}$$ for some  $m$

Assume $ k = 2^{1000}$, then take log on both sides $\log k = 1000  \log 2 \approx 301.02999 > 301$

Therefore $2^{1000}$ has $302$ digits.

Comment: 302 is correct.

Comment: That's essentially what I would have done.  If you want to double check, feel free to count the number of digits in 10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376.

Comment: @Nate: Awesome!

Comment: For a quick back-of-the-envelope computation, you can note that $2^{10}$ is only a little larger than $10^3$, so $2^{1000} = (2^{10})^{100}$ is larger than $10^{300}$, though not by much; so $2^{1000}$ should have close to, but perhaps a few more, than 300 digits.

Comment: *Offtopic*: on Unix-like machine, `echo "2^1000" | bc | tr -d '\n\r\\' | wc -m` can do such count a la Nate's comment above :)

Comment: $2^{1000} = 1024^{100} = 10^{300}x1.024^{100}$. $1.024^{100}$ = $1 + 100*0.024 + 100*99/2*0.024^2 + 100*99*98/6*0.024^3...}$, about 1 + 2.4 + 2.8512 + 2.2353 + 1.3019 + 0.5994 > 10 but definitely less than 100.

Comment: 5 years too late but to make this *perfectly* clear:  $2^m = (10^{\log_{10}2})^m=10^{m\log_{10} 2}$.  $10^k$ will have $k + 1$ digits (1 and k zeros) so $10^x$ with $k < x < k+1$ will have $x$ rounded up to the next higher integer ($k+1$).  So $2^{m}$ will have $\lceil m\log_{10} 2 \rceil= \lceil m*0.30102999566398119521373889472449.... \rceil$ .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recall that $10^{d-1}$ has $d$ digits. So for any number $n,$ the number of digits of $n$ is given by solving $ 10^{d-1} = n,$ or $$d = 1 + \lfloor \log_{10}(n) \rfloor$$

Answer (score 0):

$2^{10}=4$ digits
$2^{20}=7$ digits
from above we know that
$2^{10} = k$
$2^{20} = k+3$
Since $2^{10n}=\text{previous digits}+3$, following the process then 
$$
2^{1000} \text{ has }302\text{ digits}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Solve

$$ 10^{d} = 2^{1000}.$$

You should get an answer of approximately $301.03,$ which when rounded up gives $302.$