# Number of digits of $2^{1000}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

A friend asks me to find the number of digits of $2^{1000}$. I tried to look for a pattern by calculating the first powers of $2$ but I didn't find it. How should I proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Do not be so sure this is a friend. And I see that you mis-spelled "friend" anyway.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119913/how-many-digits-does-21000-contain

Comment: Three-hundred-something... Python says `len(str(2**1000)) = 302`.

Comment: Hint: Remember that $2^{10} = 1024 \approx 10^3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Solve for $x$ using logs:

$$10^x = 2^{1000}$$

**Spoiler**

> $x \approx 301$ digits, so round up and say $302$ digits.

Comment: I peeked! Nice work! +1

Answer (score 3):

HINT: $\log_{10}2^{1000}=1000\log_{10}2\approx 301.03$

Answer (score 1):

There are ceiling $n *\log_{10}2$ digits in $2^n$. The base $10$ log of $2$ is $.30103$, so your answer is $.30103 * 1000 \approx 302$ digits :)